# Sass - loop through array of numbers for nth-child(#{$i}) targeting

Tags: loops, sass

I'm creating a mixin to hide columns (th and td) of nth-child value sent from the include statement. What's missing in my code, or better yet, is this the best approach even if corrected to work?

**Include statement:**

```
$hidden-columns: (2, 3, 6, 9, 17);
@include hide-columns($hidden-columns);
```

**Mixin:**

```
@mixin hide-columns($columns) {
  @for $i from 0 to length($columns) {
    th:nth-child(#{$columns[ $i ]}),
    td:nth-child(#{$columns[ $i ]}) {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using @each instead of a loop (below) however, I'd still love to know the correct syntax for the loop in my original post if someone cares to post and I will mark that as the answer.

```
@mixin hide-columns($columns) {
  @each $col in $columns {
    th:nth-child(#{$col}),
    td:nth-child(#{$col}) {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
```